# A little confusion about .jar files

Tags: java, jar

In computer science I have learned that .jar files are basically a compressed set of .java files that have been compiled. So, when you have a project, instead of those 20 .java files you can have a pile of compressed classes (a .jar). Last year in CSI we worked with a .jar file called DanceStudio, which we had to use to make feet walk across the floor. This year, we are working with a different program to better understand java, so i unzipped the .jar file contained 26 classes, which I then decompiled. I wanted to try to create a program by compiling all of the .java files with the others necessary to make the program run (Walker, Foot, ETC.) When I try to compile all of these files, it will say that I have duplicate files (Walker, Foot, ETC.) What I don't understand is why this would compile if the .jar file was basically the same thing, just in a compressed form. What also confuses me is that the Foot, ETC files in the .jar are actually more complicated and have more code.

Could someone please explain how the .jar file actually works and separates these files apart, and how it could run with a duplicate class that isn't in the .jar file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you're missing one step in your explanation of a .jar file.

A `.jar` file is a collection of `.class` files. And `.class` files are what is produced by compiling a `.java` file.

*Usually* a single `.java` file will produce a single `.class` file, because it will contain a single type definition. But there are several ways for a `.java` file to produce more than one `.class` files (inner/nested classes, anonymous classes, top-level non-public classes, ...), so it's not *necessarily* a 1-to-1 association between `.java` files and `.class` files.

Then there's the confusion why the decompiled Java source code looks more complicated than the original Java source. This one is easy to answer: the compilation step was not *designed* to be reversable.

When the Java compiler turns `.java` files to `.class` files it produces a format that is best suited for being executed. That format will not represent the exact same concepts that the Java source file does. For example: there's no classical "if" in the Java bytecode. It will be implemented be appropriate jump commands.

All of this means that the process of converting `.class` files back to `.java` files is complicated and usually non-perfect.

Answer (score 0):

1. You generally compile your (clear text) .java source files into (binary) .class files.
2. If you use packages, then the class files will be in different subdirectories (representing the package).
3. A .jar file is a compressed binary file that puts all the .classes in the right directories in one compact, easy to manage file.
4. .jar file can also contain other files, such as manifests, bitmaps and resources.
5. .jar files can also be "signed" to insure the integrity/authenticity of their contents.

Here are some good links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/

'Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

About your duplicate:  Maybe your .jar is still in your build path, so when you try to compile your project with the decompiled class, you will have duplicate.  check and remove the .jar if its still in your build path.